# How to take 10 digits from the right?

Tags: vba

The code calculates the key of a bank account number.

I want to modify it to take 10 digits from the right to calculate the corresponding key.

For example:
If the number is 6465981, take it all into consideration since it is 7 digits long.
If the number is 007999990006465981, take 0006465981 to calculate the key.

The code is:

```vb
Public Function RIP(Cle_RIP As String) As String

If Cle_RIP = "" Then
   Cle_RIP = 0
End If

RIP = Cle_RIP * 100
RIP = RIP - 97 * Int(RIP / 97)
RIP = RIP + 85

If RIP < 97 Then
   RIP = RIP + 97
Else
   RIP = RIP
End If

RIP = RIP - 97
RIP = 97 - RIP

If RIP < 10 Then
   RIP = "0" & RIP
Else
   RIP = RIP
End If
End Function
```

Comment: You should put the function in the VBA editor within Excel, run the function, and place break points so you can begin to understand how the script works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Right`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/right-function) function to get the right-most part of a string, so...

```
Public Function RIP(Cle_RIP As String) As String

    Cle_RIP = Right(Cle_RIP, 10)

    If Cle_RIP = "" Then
       Cle_RIP = 0
    End If

'.....rest of your code
```